# Online jailbreak

Tags: jailbreak, ios, ipad

I heard about a service called JailbreakMe. It's an online jailbreak right through the safari browser on the iDevice, but it is not supports on iPad 1 or 3.
I have ipad 1 ios 5.1.1 and ipad 3 ios 8.4.1. How can I jailbreak one of these devices online or at least install Cydia?

Comment: http://canijailbreak.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are no userland exploits available for any recent version of iOS.
JailbreakMe is for iOS 4.2.6 through 4.2.8, or iOS 4.3 through 4.3.3.

- You can jailbreak iOS 5.1.1 with [absinthe2](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/tagged/redsn0w).
- You are currently not able to jailbreak iOS 8.4.1.